# Linq to SQL how to do “where [column] in (list of values)”

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of Fields:

```
var Fields_Of_User = (from item in db.Field_Relationship
                                  where item.User_ID == ID_Of_User
                                  select item.Field_ID
                                    ).ToList();
```

I want to select Question by list Fields

```
        var Questions = (from item in db.Questions

                                   where Fields_Of_User.Any(fieldid => fieldid.Equals(item.Field_ID))
                                   select item
                             );
```

And then I put it into Viewbag

```
ViewBag.Questions= Questions;
```

In View, I call it:

```
@foreach (var t in ViewBag.Questions)
{}
```

I got the Error:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM
>   primitive or enumeration types.

The problem in:

```
where Fields_Of_User.Any(fieldid => fieldid.Equals(item.Field_ID))
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: try `where Fields_Of_User.Any(fieldid => fieldid.Field_ID == item.Field_ID)`

Comment: it got an error in fieldid.Field_ID

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that the first query produces a list of nullable `int`s, while the search wants a list of non-nullables. Since you wouldn't match `null` anyway, you could filter for non-null values and cast to `int` in the first query:

```
var Fields_Of_User = (from item in db.Field_Relationship
    where item.User_ID == ID_Of_User && item.Field_ID != null
    select (int)item.Field_ID
).ToList();
```

The second query needs to be rewritten as follows:

```
var Questions = (from item in db.Questions
    where Fields_Of_User.Any(fieldid => fieldid == item.Field_ID)
    select item
);
```

Comment: This statements not work: Fields_Of_User.Contains(item.Field_ID)

Comment: @ThếHiệp Does the first change get your version of the second query working?

Comment: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wQ3M4oaqqcE/WA47vNy9p4I/AAAAAAAAMpU/GmaqeAbM5QMqeqi_aYseKxoRi_IiCWk8QCLcB/s1600/Untitled.jpg

Comment: @ThếHiệp You are dereferencing `Field_ID` on a value that's already an `int`. Please see the edit.

Comment: Fields_Of_User always not null

Comment: Wouldn't `Fields_Of_User.Contains(Field_ID)` be preferrable to `Fields_Of_User.Any(fieldid => fieldid == item.Field_ID)` given that `Fields_Of_User` is a List and you won't have a delegate call or generic enumeration like `Any()`?